# How can I open a new chrome tab an emulate an omnibox entry?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I'm developing a Chrome extension and need to open a number of tabs with omnibox entries filled out.

As an example, imagine typing "test" into the omnibox, it will do a Google search for "test".  However, if you type "http://test.com", it'll open that URL.  I wish to have that same behaviour.

Calling `chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'test' });` attempts to open a new tab at the URL: `chrome-extension://noaegdcbalcniptpnggbfgapjmlfxpxx/test`

Is there an omnibox protocol?  `omnibox:test` or `omnibox:http://test.com`, for example?

Or an API?  `chrome.omnibox.open('test')` or `chrome.omnibox.open('http://test.com')` for example?  (I've checked the docs, but can't find anything)

Comment: Are you trying to search using the default provider? Or specifically want to open the suggestions list for a string?

Comment: @Xan I'd like to mimic omnibox.  Sometimes that's a search, sometimes it's a http:// protocol (which just visits that URL), sometimes it might be ftp://, could be an external protocol (mailto:, steamapp://, etc).  I basically want to do whatever Chrome itself would do when that string is entered